# RegEx: Uk Landlines, Mobile phone numbers

Tags: regex, phone-number

I've been struggling with finding a suitable solution :-

I need an regex expression that will match all UK phone numbers and mobile phones.

So far this one appears to cover most of the UK numbers:

```
^0\d{2,4}[ -]{1}[\d]{3}[\d -]{1}[\d -]{1}[\d]{1,4}$
```

However mobile numbers do not work with this regex expression or phone-numbers written in a single solid block such as 01234567890.

Could anyone help me create the required regex expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this regex do?

```
//  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

/// <summary>
///  Regular expression built for C# on: Wed, Sep 8, 2010, 06:38:28 
///  Using Expresso Version: 3.0.2766, http://www.ultrapico.com
///  
///  A description of the regular expression:
///  
///  [1]: A numbered capture group. [\+44], zero or one repetitions
///      \+44
///          Literal +
///          44
///  [2]: A numbered capture group. [\s+], zero or one repetitions
///      Whitespace, one or more repetitions
///  [3]: A numbered capture group. [\(?]
///      Literal (, zero or one repetitions
///  [area_code]: A named capture group. [(\d{1,5}|\d{4}\s+?\d{1,2})]
///      [4]: A numbered capture group. [\d{1,5}|\d{4}\s+?\d{1,2}]
///          Select from 2 alternatives
///              Any digit, between 1 and 5 repetitions
///              \d{4}\s+?\d{1,2}
///                  Any digit, exactly 4 repetitions
///                  Whitespace, one or more repetitions, as few as possible
///                  Any digit, between 1 and 2 repetitions
///  [5]: A numbered capture group. [\)?]
///      Literal ), zero or one repetitions
///  [6]: A numbered capture group. [\s+|-], zero or one repetitions
///      Select from 2 alternatives
///          Whitespace, one or more repetitions
///          -
///  [tel_no]: A named capture group. [(\d{1,4}(\s+|-)?\d{1,4}|(\d{6}))]
///      [7]: A numbered capture group. [\d{1,4}(\s+|-)?\d{1,4}|(\d{6})]
///          Select from 2 alternatives
///              \d{1,4}(\s+|-)?\d{1,4}
///                  Any digit, between 1 and 4 repetitions
///                  [8]: A numbered capture group. [\s+|-], zero or one repetitions
///                      Select from 2 alternatives
///                          Whitespace, one or more repetitions
///                          -
///                  Any digit, between 1 and 4 repetitions
///              [9]: A numbered capture group. [\d{6}]
///                  Any digit, exactly 6 repetitions
///  
///
/// </summary>
public Regex MyRegex = new Regex(
      "(\\+44)?\r\n(\\s+)?\r\n(\\(?)\r\n(?<area_code>(\\d{1,5}|\\d{4}\\s+"+
      "?\\d{1,2}))(\\)?)\r\n(\\s+|-)?\r\n(?<tel_no>\r\n(\\d{1,4}\r\n(\\s+|-"+
      ")?\\d{1,4}\r\n|(\\d{6})\r\n))",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
    | RegexOptions.Singleline
    | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture
    | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
    | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
    | RegexOptions.Compiled
    );



//// Replace the matched text in the InputText using the replacement pattern
// string result = MyRegex.Replace(InputText,MyRegexReplace);

//// Split the InputText wherever the regex matches
// string[] results = MyRegex.Split(InputText);

//// Capture the first Match, if any, in the InputText
// Match m = MyRegex.Match(InputText);

//// Capture all Matches in the InputText
// MatchCollection ms = MyRegex.Matches(InputText);

//// Test to see if there is a match in the InputText
// bool IsMatch = MyRegex.IsMatch(InputText);

//// Get the names of all the named and numbered capture groups
// string[] GroupNames = MyRegex.GetGroupNames();

//// Get the numbers of all the named and numbered capture groups
// int[] GroupNumbers = MyRegex.GetGroupNumbers();
```

Notice how the spaces and dashes are optional and can be part of it.. also it is now divided into two capture groups called `area_code` and `tel_no` to break it down and easier to extract.

Comment: i tried that one with no avail :( a standard 01000 123456 failed. so far the closest i've got to perfect is: ^\s*\(?(020[7,8]{1}\)?[ ]?[1-9]{1}[0-9{2}[ ]?[0-9]{4})|(0[1-8]{1}[0-9]{3}\)?[ ]?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2}[ ]?[0-9]{3})\s*|[0-9]+[ ]?[0-9]+$ but its rather chunky

Comment: i previously implemented it incorrectly, unfortunately where i had to implement this regex wasn't ideal. However, i was given the time to refactor the whole validation and this method did  address the majority of my issues, thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
  [\d -]{1}
```

is blatently incorrect: a digit OR a space OR a hyphen.

```
  01000 123456
```

01000 is not a valid UK area code. 123456 is not a valid local number.

It is important that test data be real area codes and real number ranges.

```
  ^\s*(?(020[7,8]{1})?[ ]?[1-9]{1}[0-9{2}[ ]?[0-9]{4})|(0[1-8]{1}[0-9]{3})?[ ]?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2}[ ]?[0-9]{3})\s*|[0-9]+[ ]?[0-9]+$
```

The above pattern is garbage for many different reasons.

[7,8] matches 7 or comma or 8. You don't need to match a comma.

London numbers also begin with 3 not just 7 or 8.

London 020 numbers aren't the only 2+8 format numbers; see also 023, 024, 028 and 029.

[1-9]{1} simplifies to [1-9]

[ ]? simplifies to \s?

Having found the intial 0 once, why keep searching for it again and again?

^(0....|0....|0....|0....)$ simplifies to ^0(....|....|....|....)$

Seriously. ([1]|[2]|[3]|[7]){1}  simplifies to [1237] here.

UK phone numbers use a variety of formats: 2+8, 3+7, 3+6, 4+6, 4+5, 5+5, 5+4. Some users don't know which format goes with which number range and might use the wrong one on input. Let them do that; you're interested in the DIGITS.

**Step 1: Check the input format looks valid**

Make sure that the input looks like a UK phone number. Accept various dial prefixes, +44, 011 44, 00 44 with or without parentheses, hyphens or spaces; or national format with a leading 0. Let the user use any format they want for the remainder of the number: (020) 3555 7788 or 00 (44) 203 555 7788 or 02035-557-788 even if it is the wrong format for that particular number. Don't worry about unbalanced parentheses. The important part of the input is making sure it's the correct number of digits. Punctuation and spaces don't matter.

```
  ^\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)$
```

The above pattern matches optional opening parentheses, followed by 00 or 011 and optional closing parentheses, followed by an optional space or hyphen, followed by optional opening parentheses. Alternatively, the initial opening parentheses are followed by a literal + without a following space or hyphen. Any of the previous two options are then followed by 44 with optional closing parentheses, followed by optional space or hyphen, followed by optional 0 in optional parentheses, followed by optional space or hyphen, followed by optional opening parentheses (international format). Alternatively, the pattern matches optional initial opening parentheses followed by the 0 trunk code (national format).

The previous part is then followed by the NDC (area code) and the subscriber phone number in 2+8, 3+7, 3+6, 4+6, 4+5, 5+5 or 5+4 format with or without spaces and/or hyphens. This also includes provision for optional closing parentheses and/or optional space or hyphen after where the user thinks the area code ends and the local subscriber number begins. The pattern allows any format to be used with any GB number. The display format must be corrected by later logic if the wrong format for this number has been used by the user on input.

The pattern ends with an optional extension number arranged as an optional space or hyphen followed by x, ext and optional period, or #, followed by the extension number digits. The entire pattern does not bother to check for balanced parentheses as these will be removed from the number in the next step.

At this point you don't care whether the number begins 01 or 07 or something else. You don't care whether it's a valid area code. Later steps will deal with those issues.

**Step 2: Extract the NSN so it can be checked in more detail for length and range**

After checking the input looks like a GB telephone number using the pattern above, the next step is to extract the NSN part so that it can be checked in greater detail for validity and then formatted in the right way for the applicable number range.

```
  ^\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)(44)\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)([1-9]\d{1,4}\)?[\s\d-]+)(?:((?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)$
```

Use the above pattern to extract the '44' from $1 to know that international format was used, otherwise assume national format if $1 is null.

Extract the optional extension number details from $3 and store them for later use.

Extract the NSN (including spaces, hyphens and parentheses) from $2.

**Step 3: Validate the NSN**

Remove the spaces, hyphens and parentheses from $2 and use further RegEx patterns to check the length and range and identify the number type.

These patterns will be much simpler, since they will not have to deal with various dial prefixes or country codes.

The pattern to match valid mobile numbers is therefore as simple as

```
  ^7([45789]\d{2}|624)\d{6}$
```

Premium rate is

```
  ^9[018]\d{8}$
```

There will be a number of other patterns for each number type: landlines, business rate, non-geographic, VoIP, etc.

By breaking the problem into several steps, a very wide range of input formats can be allowed, and the number range and length for the NSN checked in very great detail.

**Step 4: Store the number**

Once the NSN has been extracted and validated, store the number with country code and all the other digits with no spaces or punctuation, e.g. 442035557788.

**Step 5: Format the number for display**

Another set of simple rules can be used to format the number with the requisite +44 or 0 added at the beginning.

The rule for numbers beginning 03 is

```
  ^44(3\d{2})(\d{3])(\d{4})$
```

formatted as

```
  0$1 $2 $3 or as +44 $1 $2 $3
```

and for numbers beginning 02 is

```
  ^44(2\d)(\d{4})(\d{4})$
```

formatted as

```
  (0$1) $2 $3 or as +44 $1 $2 $3
```

The full list is quite long. I could copy and paste it all into this thread, but it would be hard to maintain that information in multiple places over time. For the present the complete list can be found at: http://aa-asterisk.org.uk/index.php/Regular_Expressions_for_Validating_and_Formatting_GB_Telephone_Numbers

Comment: Good answer, but your link appears to be broken now :-(

Answer (score 3):

Given that people sometimes write their numbers with spaces in random places, you might be better off ignoring the spaces all together - you could use a regex as simple as this then:

^0(\d ?){10}$

This matches:

- 01234567890
- 01234 234567
- 0121 3423 456
- 01213 423456
- 01000 123456

But it would also match:

- 01 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0

So you may not like it, but it's certainly simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Strip all whitespace and non-numeric characters and then do the test. It'll be musch , much easier than trying to account for all the possible options around brackets, spaces, etc.
Try the following:

```
@"^(([0]{1})|([\+][4]{2}))([1]|[2]|[3]|[7]){1}\d{8,9}$"
```

Starts with `0` or `+44` (for international) - I;m sure you could add `0044` if you wanted.
It then has a `1`, `2`, `3` or `7`.
It then has either 8 or 9 digits.

If you want to be even smarter, the following may be a useful reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_the_United_Kingdom

Comment: +1, but can't be serious about `[0]{1}` and `[4]{2}`… oO Also, there is too much grouping going on.

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately i cannot edit the c# to strip the whitespace out of the string.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a single regex, but there's sample code from [Braemoor Software](http://www.braemoor.co.uk/software/telnumbers.shtml) that is simple to follow and fairly thorough.

The JS version is probably easiest to read. It strips out spaces and hyphens (which I realise you said you can't do) then applies a number of positive and negative regexp checks.

Answer (score 0):

Start by stripping the non-numerics, excepting a + as the first character.

(Javascript)

```
var tel=document.getElementById("tel").value;
tel.substr(0,1).replace(/[^+0-9]/g,'')+tel.substr(1).replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')
```

The regex below allows, after the international indicator +, any combination of between 7 and 15 digits (the ITU maximum) UNLESS the code is +44 (UK).  Otherwise if the string either begins with +44, +440 or 0, it is followed by 2 or 7 and then by nine of any digit, or it is followed by 1, then any digit except 0, then either seven or eight of any digit. (So 0203 is valid, 0703 is valid but 0103 is not valid).  There is currently no such code as 025 (or in London 0205), but those could one day be allocated.

```
/(^\+(?!44)[0-9]{7,15}$)|(^(\+440?|0)(([27][0-9]{9}$)|(1[1-9][0-9]{7,8}$)))/
```

Its primary purpose is to identify a correct starting digit for a non-corporate number, followed by the correct number of digits to follow. It doesn't deduce if the subscriber's local number is 5, 6, 7 or 8 digits. It does not enforce the prohibition on initial '1' or '0' in the subscriber number, about which I can't find any information as to whether those old rules are still enforced.  UK phone rules are not enforced on properly formatted international phone numbers from outside the UK.

Answer (score 0):

After a long search for valid regexen to cover UK cases, I found that the best way (if you're using client side javascript) to validate UK phone numbers is to use [`libphonenumber-js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libphonenumber-js) along with custom config to reduce bundle size:

If you're using NodeJS, generate UK metadata by running:

```sh
npx libphonenumber-metadata-generator metadata.custom.json --countries GB --extended
```

then import and use the metadata with `libphonenumber-js/core`:

```
import { isValidPhoneNumber } from "libphonenumber-js/core";
import data from "./metadata.custom.json";

isValidPhoneNumber("01234567890", "GB", data);
```

[CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/libphonenumberjs-uk-example-f5b3e)