# what is the UK Phone number validation expression and syntax?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, phone-number

```
function validateForm()
{
    var x=document.forms["pageFeedbackSurvey"]["emailAddr"].value;
    var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
            {
            alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address");
            return false;
            }

    var x=document.forms["pageFeedbackSurvey"]["comments"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="")
            {
            alert("Please enter your feedback into the textbox before pressing 'Submit'");
            return false;
            }

    var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    var pattern = /^([0-9]){7,15}$/;
        if (pattern.test(phone)) 
        {
        alert("Your phone number : "+phone);
        return true;
        } 
        alert("It is not valid phone number!");
        return false;
        }
```

then the html

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" name="pageFeedbackSurvey" id="pageFeedbackSurvey">
                            <div class="pod pageFeedback">
                                <h2>Feedback</h2>
                                <div class="body">                                  
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <div class="surveyrow">
                                            <p id="q1Wording">Did you find the information you were looking for on this page?</p>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li> <!-- input uses class, name and value for jquery -->
                                                    <input name="showdiv2" id="survey1_1" value="Yes" type="radio" class="showsubmit"/><label for="survey1_1">Yes</label>         
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <input name="showdiv" id="survey1_2" value="No" type="radio" class="showform"/><label for="survey1_2">Partially</label>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <input name="showdiv" id="survey1_3" value="No" type="radio" class="showform"/><label for="survey1_3">No</label>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>

                                        <div id="extraFields">
                                            <div class="commentRow">
                                            <div id="hiddentextarea"> <!-- hidden div -->
                                                <label for="comments">How can we improve this page?</label>
                                                <textarea name="limitedtextarea" onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.limitedtextarea,this.form.countdown,300);" 
                                                onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.limitedtextarea,this.form.countdown,300);" id="comments" rows="8" cols="19"></textarea>
                                                <p>Character limit: <input readonly="readonly" type="text" name="countdown" id="countdown" size="3" value="300"></input></p>
                                            </div>
                                            </div> <!-- end hidden div -->
                                            <div id="hiddenfields"> <!-- hidden div -->
                                            <div class="emailContainer">
                                                <div class="email" id="email">
                                                    <input type="text" name="emailAddr" id="emailAddr" size="22" value="Enter email address"/>
                                                </div>                                                  
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="phoneContainer">
                                                <div class="phone" id="phone">
                                                    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" type="phone" size="22" value="" />
                                                </div>                                                  
                                            </div>


                                            <div id="pageFeedbackSubmit" class="button primary right">
                                                <input class="arrow" onclick="validate();" value="Submit" type="submit" id="surveySubmit"/>
                                            </div><!-- button -->
                                            </div> <!-- end hidden div -->
                                            <div class="clearBoth"></div>
                                        </div>

                                    </fieldset>
                                    <div id="errormsg" class="errorMessage" style="display: none"></div>
                                    <div id="thankYou" style="display:none">                                        
                                        <h3>Thank you</h3>                                      
                                        <p>We appreciate you taking the time to help us.</p>                                                                    
                                    </div>
```

I have been struggling to find the solution to validating the phone input either on type or on submit. I have the form hidden until a radio button is selected, the email and phone and text area are shown after radio is pressed and then I have it validate the text area for input and the email for syntax, now I need to validate the phone as a uk number, I managed to get the phone field to at least show a pop up alert for not being correct, but I cannot get it to accept any number in the current setup.

Can someone advise me of the correct way to have the phone validated along with the email and text area at same time as validateForm function is actioned on submit?

---

### all below added/edited 23/08/2012

hey guys thanks for all the replys but I still cant get it to work, I have changed the id so there is not 2 `phone` id anymore, i changed showdiv2 to showdiv and i changed input type to tel before i inserted javascript telnumber check

I added the script from braemoor.co.uk/software/telnumbers.shtml to a javascript file in my header i then tried to tie in that javascript to the html, there was no html on that example so i have been guessing...

the validation function already in place for the email and the text area are initiated by

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()"
```

this works fine, what i want is for the telephone function also to be run on submit or before? I have tried adding it to the submit button as

```
<input class="arrow" onclick="checkUKTelephone();" value="Submit" type="submit" id="surveySubmit"/>
```

but it does not validate the phone it just forwards to the demo page after its validated email and text area ignoring the telephone number, obviously im not doing something right i dont have a great deal of experience with javascript as your may have noticed :)

anyone kind enough to tell me where im going wrong?

Comment: Why do you need to validate a phone number? The only _real_ way to validate it is to call it and see who picks up. Phone numbers don't have parity in them like most bank account numbers, pretty much anything goes really.

Comment: First you have a mistake in your html code : `name="showdiv"` instade of `name="showdiv2"`
For the phone number validation for the UK there are many advanced validators available online example http://www.braemoor.co.uk/software/telnumbers.shtml and the code is available on the bottom of the page

Comment: @jidma oh yes jidma i forgot about that I had a different set up earlier and needed 2 sets of hidden divs meaning 2 names needed for selection ... il change that

Comment: @frits van campen   hi thanks for your reply I need it validated as the company asked me to make sure only uk numbers get entered into the form - just following orders :) -

Comment: @WebDevMaster how about the link i sent you, seems to contain an advanced validator for UK.

Comment: @jidma thankyou jidma il have a look at that tomorrow im about to go to bed now il post back here if i get it working or not using that link cheers

Comment: @WebDevMaster np, plus don't forget to fix the problem in your HTML (id="phone" twice as mentioned in my answer), that's actually why you can never validate the phone number..

Comment: Why aren't you using `<input type="tel">`? http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.tel.html  (won't help validation of course but it will help users)

Comment: @jidma hello again jidma i have put in place all of the fixes mentioned in this post and added/edited my original question at the bottom. i have tried implementing the code from braemoor.co.uk/software/telnumbers.shtml but my experience has failed me :(, details are at bottom of my question

Comment: @WebDevMaster i updated my answer with a complete code (google docs link at the end) you can give it a try as is and then integrate it with your code.
Let me know if you need any further assistance

Comment: The post at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669516/regex-uk-landlines-mobile-phone-numbers/13296860#13296860   should help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your HTML:

```
<div class="phoneContainer">
    <div class="phone" id="phone">
       <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" type="phone" size="22" value="" />
    </div>                                                  
</div>
```

As you can see, the id "phone" is there twice for the DIV and the INPUT.

So when you try to get the phone number you want to validate it returns "undefined", and that's what you validate instade of the actual phone number.

```
<div class="phoneContainer">
    <div class="phone" id="phoneDiv"> <!-- change the name here -->
       <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" type="phone" size="22" value="" />
    </div>                                                  
</div>
```

In an HTML document, two Elements can have the same name, but the id should be uniq.

For a complete example based on your code, check : https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B31oh4Omo6z0YjFmNHc2bjJCMk0